# Hibernate Second level cache doesn't work for OneToOne associations

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hibernate-cache

I am trying to enable Hibernate's 2nd level cache but cannot avoid multiple queries being issued for OneToOne relations.

My models are:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Business {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "business", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Address address;
}

@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Address {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_id", unique = true, nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_business_id"))
    private Business business;
}
```

When I run `session.get(Business.class, id)` with the `Business` with id `id` in the cache, no query is issued for loading `Business` but it does for `Address`.

I understand that Address is the relation owner and that in the Business cache entry there's no `Address.id` information, but wouldn't it be possible to solve this problem by applying the same mechanism as *ToMany relations does, creating a new cache region for each field? Assuming Business 1 is related to Address 2, there would be the following regions and entries in my cache after a first load:

```
Business
  Business#1         -> [business model]
Business.address
  Business.address#1 -> [2]
Address
  Address#2          -> [address model]
```

I have tried to make it work by annotating `Address.business` with `@NaturalId` and the `Address` class with `@NaturalIdCache`. The cache region is created and populated but `session.get(Business.class, id)` does not use it.

My `Business` model has many more OneToOne relations whose foreign key is on the other side (not the Business) and we must list several at a time so the database server has to process dozens of queries per HTTP request.

I have read the Hibernate's User Guide, Vlad Mihalcea's explanation on 2LC and its in-memory dehydrated format, Baeldung's explanation and several other StackOverflow answers and cannot find a way to solve this.

Comment: any update on this one?